# How do I split string into a list of Chinese chars in Python3 under Linux

Tags: python, linux

I tried the following code in python3 with both windows and linux OS, but I got different results. I am wondering how to split a string into a list of characters instead of unicode bytes.

code:

```
#encoding=utf-8
s = '我也不知道lll'
chars = list(s)
for char in chars:
    print(char)
```

linux env: python3.6 gcc4.4
windows env: python3.7

linux output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(char)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u6211' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

windows output:

```
我
也
不
知
道
l
l
l
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

This will explicitly set your encoding system to `UTF-8`